# how to show hidden div on li:hover?

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a php page displaying query results from mysql.  This result is displayed in an unordered list `<li>`.  I have also a div, initially hidden inside of each `<li>` tag, that should showup on hover.  I have tried this using jquery with this:

```
$('#results li').mouseover(function() { 
   $('.theoption').show();
}).mouseleave(function() {$('.theoption').hide()});
```

This displays the hidden div.  The problem is it displays on all `<li>` tags at the same time.  How can I change the code so that the div only displays on the currently hovered `<li>`?

many thanks.

Comment: is the div inside the li tag?

Comment: Please show us some generated markup, the details are important and they're not clear from your description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the div is **inside** the li tag you can use plain ol' css:

```
#results li:hover div.theoption {
     display: block;
}
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$('#results li').hover(function(){
     $('.theoption', this).show();  //find the div INSIDE this li
},function(){
     $('.theoption', this).hide();
});
```

Comment: If your divs aren't already inside the LI, they probably should be. Then Neal's solution will work. The important thing to understand is the two-parameter selector. The first is the target, but after the comma is the context. As per the commented code, "Find .theoption inside of THIS hovered element (the LI).

Comment: @SaintShann if this solution works you should be more precise when asking a question!

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details @Teneff. I'll try to be thorough next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#results li').mouseover(function() { 
    $(this).find('.theoption').show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('.theoption').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `<div>` is next to the `<li>` you can also use plain CSS:

```
#results li:hover + div.theoption {
    display: block;
}
```

[CSS 2 - Partern Matching](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)

if you insist using jQuery that's how it could be done:

```
$('#results li').hover(function(){
    $(this).next().show();
}, function(){
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```